# OSMBonusPack Markers doesn't display bubble after switching to landscape

Tags: android, dictionary, android-activity, openstreetmap, osmdroid

This is my problem...it may be simple but i'm stuck:

**Context**

I have some informations that i downloaded from Internet  (text and small imgs), and i want to  display it inside the bubble when i tap inside myMarkers class. I want that this work both landscape and not.

**Problem**

When the app is portrait and when i kill the application and i re-run it,  all is working (when i tap i see the bubble with text and img).
When i turn to landscape and when my app is not visible but alive, the map restore markers but when i tap on them, they doesn't display the bubble.

**Code**

Here my implementation of *Marker* that implements `Parcelable` in order to save them into the `Bundle` when i call `onSaveInstanceState` when my Activity go onPause() (ommitted empty override methods) :

```
class myMarker extends Marker implements Parcelable{

            public myMarker(MapView mapView) {
                    super(mapView);
            }

            public  Parcelable.Creator<myMarker> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<myMarker>() {

            public myMarker createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new myMarker(map);
            }

            public myMarker[] newArray(int size) {
                return new myMarker[size];
            }
            };

}
```

Inside the `onCreate()` in the Activity we have:

```
 if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // Restore myMarkers
    markers = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("MARKERS");
    for (int i=0;i<markers.size();i++){                  
         map.getOverlays().add(markers.get(i));
         Marker m=markers.get(i);

            }
         map.invalidate();
        } 
 else {
    markers=new ArrayList<myMarker>();
        }
```

And the saving process:

```
@Override
      public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          // Save the user's current state
          savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("MARKERS", markers);

          // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
          super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      }
```

What am i doing wrong? I'm missing something? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I resolved**

There is an issue i think. Every time that you turn the device on landscape, the `Marker`'s `MarkerInfoWindow` has an old reference to the `Context` and that's why the bubble is not shown on click. *(maybe can be fixed using fragments...)*

Just rewrite the class and when recreate the markers you just pass the new reference to the context.

The code:

```
public class myMarker extends Marker implements Parcelable{
    InfoWindow i;
    MapView map;
    static Context context=null;
    static MarkerInfoWindow ma=null;



    public myMarker(MapView mapView) {
    super(mapView);
    Context c=mapView.getContext();
   /*IF THE CONTEXT CHANGES, I KEEP MY NEW (RECREATED) mapView AND I SET A NEW static 
   MarkerInfoWindow OTHERWISE AT ANY CASE I SET THE static markerInfoWindow TO THE MARKER */
    if(context==null||context!=c){
    i=super.mInfoWindow;
    map=mapView;
    context=c;
    String packageName=context.getPackageName();
    int layoutResId=context.getResources().getIdentifier("layout/bonuspack_bubble",null,packageName);
    ma=new MarkerInfoWindow(layoutResId, mapView);
    }
    super.setInfoWindow(ma);


}
...
}
```

And the onRestore, when you reload the map in landscape, after onSave:

```
/*@ onRestore i keep my old markers and i create new markers with same info but with new mapView(new Context)*/
      @Override
      protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){                
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

              if (savedInstanceState != null) {


                  /*NEW MARKERS EQUALS TO THE OLD BUT WITH NEW MAP (NEW CONTEXT)
                  ...AND NO YOU CANT JUST UPDATE THE CONTEXT*/

                   ArrayList<myMarker> markers2;
                    markers2 = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("MARKERS");

                    if(markers2!=null){
                   for (int i=0;i<markers2.size();i++){
                       myMarker m=new myMarker(map);
                       m.setTitle(markers2.get(i).getTitle());
                       m.setImage(markers2.get(i).getImage());
                       m.setPosition(markers2.get(i).getPosition());
                       m.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
                       markers.add(m);

                            map.getOverlays().add(m);


                         }
                    }


                        map.invalidate();                  
             }

                else markers=new ArrayList<myMarker>();  




      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I confirm, you discovered an issue in the OSMBonusPack Marker (I'm the developer)
=> The static MarkerInfoWindow mDefaultInfoWindow doesn't support MapView changes.

You found one example: changing orientation, and your constructor seems a good approach to fix it.

But there are other cases: having multiple MapView in the same application. More complex.

I will try to fix that issue directly inside the lib. 
You can follow the progress in the project Issues ([issue #58](http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/issues/detail?id=58&thanks=58&ts=1395253245)).

Comment: Ok thanks awesome library considering that is free. I will follow the issue and i posted also on the google groups! thanks!